# ios swift siesta ResourceObserver resourceRequestProgress never called

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

I am using Siesta for REST calls and I am trying to create a simple ResourceObserver to display a SVProgressHUD.

```
open class SVProgressHUDResourceObserver: ResourceObserver {
    static let sharedInstance = SVProgressHUDResourceObserver()

    // Show/Hide SVProgressHUD
    public func resourceRequestProgress(for resource: Resource, progress: Double) {
        print("SVProgressHUDResourceObserver resourceRequestProgress - progress=\(progress)")
        if progress == 1 {
            print("SVProgressHUD.dismiss()")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        } else if !SVProgressHUD.isVisible() {
            print("show()")
            SVProgressHUD.show()
        }
    }

    public func resourceChanged(_ resource: Resource, event: ResourceEvent) {
        print("SVProgressHUDResourceObserver resourceChanged  event=\(event)")
    }
}
```

Since it's a singleton I add the observer using a weak reference:

```
@discardableResult func login(_ username: String, _ password: String,
                                  onSuccess: @escaping (LoginResponse) -> Void,
                                  onFailure: @escaping (Int?, String) -> Void) -> Request {
        return service.resource("/app/v1/authentication/login")
            .addObserver(SVProgressHUDResourceObserver.sharedInstance)
            .request(.post, json: [
                "username": username,
                "password": password
                ])
            .onSuccess { entity in
                guard let loginResponse: LoginResponse = entity.typedContent() else {
                    onFailure(0, "JSON parsing error")
                    return
                }
                self.authToken = loginResponse.session.token
                SessionManager.beginNewSession(loginResponse)
                onSuccess(loginResponse)
            }
            .onFailure { (error) in
                onFailure(error.httpStatusCode, error.userMessage)
        }
    }
```

I purposely added a 10 second delay to the login however the SVProgressHUD never displays, in-fact the resourceRequestProgress method is never called.  The authentication process work great.

The log output is:

```
SVProgressHUDResourceObserver resourceChanged  event=observerAdded
SVProgressHUDResourceObserver resourceChanged  event=newData(wipe)
```

Any assistance on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in Siesta between:

1. the *state of the whole resource itself*, which Siesta caches and keeps around for anyone to observe, and
2. the *results of individual requests* relating to the resource, which Siesta sends to request hooks but ultimately discards once the request is deallocated.

Note that with #1, observers keep getting notifications if *anyone* updates the state of the resource, whereas with #2 only the hook specifically registered for that request get notifications.

These two carry different kinds of information. #1 is for updates to the ongoing shared truth of the state of a resource (“the current user’s profile”) whereas #2 is for updates about the state of a specific *action* on the resource (“changing the user’s password”).

Take some time to digest “[Request vs. Load](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/requests/#request-vs-load)” in the user guide. Then, once you’ve made sense of that, read on.

---

In this code, you are attaching `SVProgressHUDResourceObserver.sharedInstance` as an observer of the resource itself:

```
    return service.resource("/app/v1/authentication/login")
        .addObserver(SVProgressHUDResourceObserver.sharedInstance)
```

…which means it will only get notifications of `load()` requests. But you never `load` it; you only `request` it:

```
        .request(.post, json: [
            "username": username,
            "password": password
            ])
```

…which means that only the request hooks (`onSuccess`, `onFailure`) that you attach to *that specific request* will be notified that it’s completed.

---

If you only need a progress bar, ditch `ResourceObserver` and use the [`onProgress`](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Protocols/Request.html#/s:6Siesta7RequestP10onProgressxySdcF) hook of the request instead.

(If you need to save the result of the login, then the user guide lays out how to update the resource’s state in response to a post request. However, it looks like you are already storing the auth credentials through other means, which is a typical and fine approach.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an excellent answer.  It was extremely helpful.