# Siesta REST login

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

How to translate my login user `URLSession` code into [Siesta framework](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta) code?  My current attempt isn't working.

I've looked at the example in the GithubBrowser but the API I have doesn't work like that.

The issue is that the user structure is kind of **split** by how the endpoint in the API I'm consuming works.  The endpoint is `http://server.com/api/key`.  Yes, it really is called `key` and not `user` or `login`.  Its called that by the authors because you post a user/pass pair and get a key back.  So it *takes in* (via post) a json struct like:

```
{"name": "bob", "password": "s3krit"}
```

and returns *as a response*:

```
{"token":"AEWasBDasd...AAsdga"}
```

I have a `SessionUser` struct:

```
struct SessionUser: Codable
{
    let name: String
    let password: String
    let token: String
}
```

...which encapsulates the **state** (the "S" in REST) for the user.  The trouble is name & password get *posted* and token is the *response*.

When this state changes I do my:

```
service.invalidateConfiguration()  // So requests get config change
service.wipeResources()            // Scrub all unauthenticated data
```

An instance is stored in a singleton, which is picked up by the configure block so that the token from the API is put in the header for all other API requests:

```
    configure("**") {
        // This block ^ is run AGAIN when the configuration is invalidated
        // even if loadManifest is not called again.
        if let haveToken = SessionManager.shared.currentUser?.token
        {
            $0.headers["Authorization"] = haveToken
        }
    }
```

That token injection part is already working well, by the way.  Yay, Siesta!

**URLSession version**

This is bloated compared to Siesta, and I'm now not using this but here is what it used to be:

```
func login(user: SessionUser, endpoint: URL)
{
    DDLogInfo("Logging in: \(user.name) with \(user.password)")

    let json: [String: Any] = ["name": user.name, "password": user.password]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    var request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    _currentStatus = .Unknown

    weak var welf = self
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            handleLogin(error: error, message: "No data from login attempt")
            return
        }
        let jsonData:Any
        do {
            jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        }
        catch let jsonDecodeError {
            handleLogin(error: jsonDecodeError, message: "Could not get JSON from login response data")
            return
        }
        guard let jsonDecoded = jsonData as? [String: Any] else {
            handleLogin(error: error, message: "Could not decode JSON as dictionary")
            return
        }
        guard let token = jsonDecoded["token"] as? String else {
            handleLogin(error: error, message: "No auth token in login response")
            return
        }
        let newUser = SessionUser(name: user.name, password: "", token: token)
        welf?.currentUser = newUser
        welf?.saveCurrentSession()
        welf?._currentStatus = .LoggedIn
        DDLogInfo("User \(newUser.name) logged in")
        loginUpdate(user: newUser, status: .LoggedIn, message: nil, error: nil)
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

**Siesta Version**

Here is my attempt right now:

```
func login(user: String, pass: String, status: @escaping (String?) -> ())
{
    let json = [ "name": user, "password": pass]
    let req = ManifestCloud.shared.keys.request(.post, json: json)
    req.onSuccess { (tokenInfo) in
        if let token = tokenInfo.jsonDict["token"] as? String
        {
            let newUser = SessionUser(name: user, password: pass, token: token)
            self.currentUser = newUser
        }
        status("success")
    }
    req.onFailure { (error) in
        status(error.userMessage)
    }
    req.onCompletion { (response) in
        status(nil)
    }
}
```

Its sort of working, but the log in credentials are not saved by Siesta and I've had to rig up a new notification system for login state which I'd hoped Siesta would do for me.

I want to use Siesta's caching so that the SessionUser object is cached locally and I can use it to get a new token, if required, using the cached credentials.  At the moment I have a jury-rigged system using `UserDefaults`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I love the word `welf`! That’s a new one to me.

Comment: I wish I had invented it but I can't recall where I saw it first.  :-)  Weak self - so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you are requesting but not loading the resource. [Siesta draws a distinction between those two things](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/requests/#request-vs-load): the first is essentially a fancied-up URLSession request; the second means that Siesta hangs on to some state and notifies observers about it.

Funny thing, I just answered a [different but related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621617/239816) about this a few minutes ago! You might find that answer a helpful starting point.

In your case, the problem is here:

```
let req = ManifestCloud.shared.keys.request(.post, json: json)
```

That `.request(…)` means that only your request hooks (`onSuccess` etc.) receive a notification when your POST request finishes, and Siesta doesn’t keep the state around for others to observe.

You would normally accomplish that by using `.load()`; however, that creates a GET request and you need a POST. You probably want to [promote your POST to be a full-fledge load request](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/requests/#promoting-a-request-to-be-a-load) like this:

```
let keysResource = ManifestCloud.shared.keys
let req = keysResource.load(using:
    keysResource.request(.post, json: json))
```

This will take whatever that POST request returns and make it the (observable) `latestData` of `ManifestCloud.shared.keys`, which should give you the “notification system for login state” that you’re looking for.

Comment: Ah - this is perfect!  Thanks Paul.  From your post I went and looked for the Siesta doc on `load(using:)` and its just what I needed.